# Oracle Bulk inserts through ADO.NET (C#) - Can't use ODP

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

Trying to do oracle bulk inserts quickly, im currently doing 4000 rows in about 110 seconds...awful! I do have my inserts tied to a transaction and only commit once the transaction is completed. I am binding parameters to the OracleCommand for input.

I'm using ADO.NET with C# parsing through the OCI. ODP.NET is really not an option because I cannot sacrifice portability. I want to distribute the application, and a few DLLs..not an oracle client install!

Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by "ADO.NET with C# parsing through the OCI" ? please show some source code...

Comment: ADO.NET is microsoft's oracle drive (System.Data.OracleClient). OCI is the Oracle Call Interface - basically just DLLs to serve the purpose of an oracle install.

Comment: thanks - I know what ADO.NET and OCI are, I don't understand the "parsing through" part...

Comment: Technially, ADO.net is a vendor neutral data interface library. System.Data.OracleClient is is Microsoft's depreciated Oracle client. They don't support it anymore and don't want people using it in new projects. Also, I don't get how you're using OCI without an Oracle client install, since OCI is an Oracle client interface.

Comment: OCI = oracle call interface isnt it?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html

Comment: Yes, and OCI is provided by the Oracle client. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to use ODP.net. That's going to be the best way to get this running more smoothly.

To get around the install a client problem, [take a look at this Oracle forums thread on a DLL only deployment that you can bundle with your app](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2185317). It's MUCH more compact then a full Oracle client install, and doesn't require any kind of installation.

Comment: The "Limitations" part of that post worry me. It really does not seem all that portable. I want to be able to distribute just my .EXE and several DLLs. Or am I misunderstanding the post?

Comment: The limitations are stuff like other programs can't use the included DLLs because they're not in the GAC and necessary registry keys aren't set. For your single app that won't matter because you're including them. You also have to use an ezconnect connection string rather then a TNS, but you can't use TNS with the Microsoft client anyway. In your specific case I don't see anything there that would affect you.

Comment: Okay Tirdus, thanks. I'm trying it now. Got the error:

"A first chance exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

I am trying to catch OracleException but am getting a null exception.

Comment: Your best bet to troubleshoot that is going to be to read through the rest of the thread and see what other people with the same issue did, and ask there if need be. There's more people with experience doing this on the ODP.net forum then on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `System.Data.OracleClient` is **deprecated** according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.aspx

IF a commercial library is an option (min. 2 DLLs) take a look at http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/ - it has a "direct mode" which works without any client install and it can use OCI if present...